# convert a string to its codepoint in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

there are characters like `'‌'` that are not visible so I cant copy paste it. I want to convert any character to its codepoint like `'\u200D'`

another example is: `'abc' => '\u0061\u0062\u0063'`

Comment: `'abc'` and `'\u0061\u0062\u0063'` are two different string literals representing the exact same string. There is no conversion to perform.

Comment: "convert any character to its unicode" doesn't make sense - that's not what "Unicode" means.

Comment: What does this have to do with copy pasting? Note that ``'‌'`` *can* be copy/pasted; it corresponds to the unicode code point 8204 or \u200c.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`'\u0061\u0062\u0063'.encode('utf-8')` will encode the text to Unicode.

Edit:

Since python automatically converts the string to Unicode you can't see the value but you can create a function that will generate that.

```
def get_string_unicode(string_to_convert):
    res = ''

    for letter in string_to_convert:
        res += '\\u' + (hex(ord(letter))[2:]).zfill(4)

    return res
```

Result:

```
>>> get_string_unicode('abc') 
'\\u0061\\u0062\\u0063'
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked!!!
for some other characters like emojis, we should use \\U000 istead of \\u so I used ```res = res + ('\\u' + hex(ord(letter))[2:]).zfill(4) if len((hex(ord(letter))[2:]))<5 else res + '\\U000'+(hex(ord(letter))[2:]).zfill(4)```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to rephrase your question. The header *convert a string to its codepoint in python* clearly did not get through to everyone, mostly, I think, because we can't imagine what you want it for.

What you want is a string containing a representation of Unicode escapes.

You can do that this way:

```
print(''.join("\\u{:04x}".format(b) for b in b'abc'))
\u0061\u0062\u0063
```

If you display that printed value as a string literal you will see doubled backslashes, because backslashes have to be escaped in a Python string. So it will look like this:

```
'\\u0061\\u0062\\u0063'
```

The reason for that is that if you simply put unescaped backslashes in your string literal, like this:

```
a = "\u0061\u0062\u0063"
```

when you display `a` at the prompt you will get:

```
>>> a
'abc'
```

Comment: This is working on bytes, not unicode characters. Just because ``abc`` happens to have the same code points in both does not make that equivalent.